# Nginx status per vhost

Tags: nginx, stats

Is there any nginx plugin that can display the stats that normal mod_status is displaying, but per vhost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry bump old post, but now you can use this module to see traffic status per vhost

https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts

You need to manually re-compile your nginx, and add this block to your site config

```
    location /status {
        vhost_traffic_status_display;
        vhost_traffic_status_display_format html;
    }
```